# how to pass java.sql.date from java class to sqlserver stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

i want to pass java.sql.date parameter from my java class to sqlserver datetime parameter with the help of stored procedure. But it is not working.
calling stored procedure from java:-

```
java.util.Date d1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(obj.getDoj());
//obj,getDoj is String.
java.util.Date d2= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(obj.getDob());
CallableStatement cs=con.prepareCall("execute insert_manager ?,?,?,?,?,?");
cs.setString(1,obj.getName());
cs.setString(2, obj.getPassword());
doj=new java.sql.Date(d1.getTime());
dob=new java.sql.Date(d2.getTime());
cs.setDate(3,doj);
cs.setDate(4, dob);
cs.setInt(5, obj.getSalary());
cs.setString(6, obj.getLocation());
boolean b = cs.execute();
```

stored procedure:=

```
create procedure insert_manager @username varchar(20),@password varchar(20),                                              
@doj dateTime,@dob dateTime,@salary int,@location varchar(20)as    
begin...........
```

---

When I used try/catch I find out that error comes in line cs.execute. Error is:

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 6 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type datetime. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.

Comment: Please can anybody help me in this...

Comment: error is in-- cs.setDate(3,doj) and cs.setDate(4.dob)

Comment: `It's not working` is not enough, please describe the problem you are having **in detail**.

Comment: ok. when i used try catch i find out that error comes in line cs.execute . Error is: "The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 6 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type datetime. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision."

Comment: i changed datatype of table column and as well as procedure variables from dateTime to date but it gave me the same error.

Comment: but if i execute this procedure manually in database like :                                execute insert_manager 'nitin','nitin','2011-08-11','1993-12-02',100000,'delhi';      It works fine.